# How to rearrange the array value using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to rearrange the following array of data using Angular.js or Javascript.

```
$scope.listOfData=[
             {
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
         {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222}
      },
     {
         {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':3333},
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':4444}
     }
]
```

I need to rearrange the above array of data like below format.

```
$scope.array=[
              {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00 to 2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order':[{'order_status':1,'order_id':'1111'},{'order_status':'0','order_id':'2222'} ]},
              {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59 to 2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order':[{'order_status':1,'order_id':'3333'},{'order_status':'0','order_id':'4444'} ]}
]
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: please make the data valid.

Comment: So, what's your question? "I need" doesn't count.

Comment: Your grouping by date range right? What are the rules around the grouping? Just giving one data-set and then another is not good enough. We need to know to rules to take it from one to the other..

Comment: I need to rearrange all set of data of each index of(0th,1st,....) from `$scope.listOfData`  into one because some key values are same `e.g-name,email,etc..`.

Comment: @ste2425 :,Yes,you are also right.

Comment: what do you do with different dates?

Comment: @NinaScholz : I will make all date from lower to higher into one date for date key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one loop proposal with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

and two temporary objects for the data and dates.

```js
var listOfData = [
        { 'date': '2016-01-25 18:14:00', 'name': 'raj', 'email': 'raj@gmail.com', 'order_status': 1, 'order_id': 1111 },
        { 'date': '2016-02-04 11:26:05', 'name': 'raj', 'email': 'raj@gmail.com', 'order_status': 0, 'order_id': 2222 },
        { 'date': '2016-01-23 13:15:59', 'name': 'rahul', 'email': 'rahul@gmail.com', 'order_status': 1, 'order_id': 3333 },
        { 'date': '2016-01-25 18:14:00', 'name': 'rahul', 'email': 'rahul@gmail.com', 'order_status': 0, 'order_id': 4444 }
    ],
    compact = function (data) {
        var object = {},
            date = {},
            array = [];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var k = a.name + '|' + a.email;
            date[k] = date[k] || { from: a.date, to: a.date };
            if (a.date < date[k].from) {
                date[k].from = a.date;
            }
            if (a.date > date[k].to) {
                date[k].to = a.date;
            }
            if (!object[k]) {
                object[k] = { date: a.date, name: a.name, email: a.email, order: [] };
                array.push(object[k]);
            }
            object[k].date = date[k].from + ' to ' + date[k].to;
            object[k].order.push({ order_status: a.order_status, order_id: a.order_id });
        });
        return array;
    }(listOfData);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(compact, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @ Nina Scholz : Its good but here also i need the lower date as from date and higher date as to date for date key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- Sort array based on `name` or `email id`.
- Sort this array based on dates.
- Create an object with necessary properties.

```js
var arr = [{
  'date': '2016-01-25 18:14:00',
  'name': 'raj',
  'email': 'raj@gmail.com',
  'order_status': 1,
  'order_id': 1111
}, {
  'date': '2016-02-04 11:26:05',
  'name': 'raj',
  'email': 'raj@gmail.com',
  'order_status': 0,
  'order_id': 2222
}, {
  'date': '2016-01-23 13:15:59',
  'name': 'rahul',
  'email': 'rahul@gmail.com',
  'order_status': 1,
  'order_id': 3333
}, {
  'date': '2016-01-25 18:14:00',
  'name': 'rahul',
  'email': 'rahul@gmail.com',
  'order_status': 0,
  'order_id': 4444
}]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  return 0
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return +new Date(a.date) - +new Date(b.date);
});

var result = {}
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!result[item.name]) {
    result[item.name] = {};
    result[item.name].orders = [];
  }

  if (!result[item.name].startDate)
    result[item.name].startDate = item.date
  else
    result[item.name].endDate = item.date

  result[item.name].name = item.name;
  result[item.name].email = item.email;
  result[item.name].orders.push({
    "order_status": item.order_status,
    "order_id": item.order_id,
    "order_date": item.date
  });
});

console.log(result);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This code can not run here.Could you make a small plunkr example.

Comment: Can you explain? I gives me output. Note I have use normal variable instead of `$scope`

Comment: @ Rajesh : Ok,but name also should come like email.it is coming like a key now.

Comment: @subhra, I had purposely ignored it since thats the name of key inside object. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ Rajesh :Ok,now its coming properly and thanks but key like `rahul,raj` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for operating over array.

```js
var listOfData=[
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
         {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222},
         {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':3333},
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':4444},
];
  
  var grouped = _.chain(listOfData).groupBy(function(each){ return each.name+each.email}).map(function(each){ return {date:_.chain(each).pluck('date').value().join(' to '),name:_.first(each).name,email:_.first(each).email,order:_.chain(each).map(function(e1) { return {order_status:e1.order_status,order_id:e1.order_id} }).value()}}).value();
  
  console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```